# Remove same value in Lists within a Dictionary in C# - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the next Dictionary of List: 

 `Dictionary<int, List<int>> links_dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();`

This object has these values:

```
1:{[7,8,3]},2:{[1,3]},3:{[4,8]},4:{[8]}
```

Is there a LINQ way for remove the same value of all lists within a Dictionary?

For example if I remove '8' from it, the new Dictionary will be:

```
1:{[7,3]},2:{[1,3]},3:{[4]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just re-project

```
var results = links_dict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Where(y => y != 8).ToList());
```

If you need to remove the empty keys, you could check after the fact. It might give you better performance

```
foreach (var item in results.Where(item => item.Value?.Any() != true))
   results.Remove(item.Key);
```

Or

```
var results = links_dict.Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value.Where(y => y != 8).ToList()))
                        .Where(x => x.Item2?.Any() == true)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);
```

Or keeping the original Dictionary

```
foreach (var key in links_dict.Keys.ToList())
   links_dict[key] = links_dict[key].Where(x => x != 8).ToList();

foreach (var item in links_dict.Where(item => item.Value?.Any() != true).ToList())
   links_dict.Remove(item.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks, It works! Is there a way to modify the same Dictionary or I must to assign to other object?

Comment: The second way doesn't remove empty keys and the third one throws a System.InvalidOperationException in first foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks! In the second way you have to modify the conditional "!= true" in Where condition to "== true" and the third one throws a System.InvalidOperationException in second foreach loop